# Can't make a function that cut a part of a char array (C99)

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, char, c-strings

I'm trying to make a function that cut a part of a string so that at the desired position, and for the desired length, it removes the part.

I'm getting **SIGSEGV error** (segmentation fault) while running with the debugger at the "Str[Pos] = 0". I don't understand why because I'm just trying to make the char pointer at this specific position set to 0 or '\0' so that it acts like it is the end of the array.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char * String = malloc(512);
    String = "Blobfish is the best creature ever made by nature";

    CutString(String, 3, 4);

    print("%s", String);
}

bool CutString(char * Str, int Pos, int Size)
{
    int StrLen = strlen(Str);
    printf("After4\n");

    if (Size < 1 || Size + Pos > StrLen) return true;
    printf("After4.1\n");

    char * StrPos = Str + Pos + Size;
    printf("After4.2\n");
    printf("%s", StrPos);

    Str[Pos] = 0;

    printf("After4.3\n");

    strcat(Str, StrPos);
    printf("After4.4\n");

    return false;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help and take care in these times,
Jules.

Comment: Please show how you call this function

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Jules RC, the problem is in the unposted calling code.  `CutString()` should not attempt to change data belonging to a _string literal_.  A good answer needs a [mcve]

Comment: What is `Str`? What is `Pos`? Does `Str` point to a valid address in memory?

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *7.24.3.1 The strcat function Synopsis
1
#include <string.h>
char \*strcat(char \* restrict s1,
const char \* restrict s2);*

Comment: `String = "Blobfish is the best creature ever made by nature";` assigns the pointer to point at a string literal, which is not modifiable

Comment: Use `strcpy` instead. Or `char String[] = "Blobfish is the best creature ever made by nature";`

Comment: C99 draft standard n1256: *7.21.3.1 The strcat function Synopsis
1
#include <string.h>
char \*strcat(char \* restrict s1,
const char \* restrict s2);*

Comment: Jules RC, For completeness, what did you expect `printf("%s", String);` to print?

Comment: @Jules RC Changing the code in question to match an answer invalidates the answer.  Post rolled back.

Comment: @Reinstate Monica I know but it's because I made a fast example so that we could test the code but I made a little mistake while making it. It has nothing to do with the question and that's why I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is invalid but it is enough to point to that the program in any case has undefined behavior because it tries to modify a string literal and modifying a string literal results in undefined behavior.

```
char * String = malloc(512);
String = "Blobfish is the best creature ever made by nature";
CutString(String, 3, 4);
//...
```

Moreover there is a memory leak because at first a memory was allocated and pointer to the memory was assigned to the pointer String. And then the pointer String was reassigned with the address of a string literal. So the address of the allocated memory is lost.

As for the function then it can be defined the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * CutString( char * s, size_t pos, size_t n )
{
    size_t length = strlen( s );

    if ( pos < length )
    {
        n = length - pos < n ? length - pos : n;

        memmove( s + pos, s + pos + n, length - pos - n + 1 );
    }

    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[]  = "Blobfish is the best creature ever made by nature";

    puts( s );
    puts( CutString( s, 3, 4 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Blobfish is the best creature ever made by nature
Bloh is the best creature ever made by nature
```

Pay attention to that there is no great sense when the function has the return type bool. It is much better when such a function returns pointer to the string itself after its modification. All standard C string functions follow this convention.

Answer (score 1):

Code is attempting to change a *string literal* which is *undefined behavior*.

Instead, modify allocated memory.

```
char * String = malloc(512);

// The below only copies the pointer to the string literal, not the string contents.
// String = "Blobfish is the best creature ever made by nature";

strcpy(String, "Blobfish is the best creature ever made by nature");
```

Comment: I made a fast example because the code itself is way too big. Corrected it.

Comment: Your "corrected it" code matched the answers.  Now things are quite unclear.  Rather than  fast example, append updates if needed to re-sate the question.  Reviews the needs for a [MCVE] including expected output.  Suggest [Help Center > Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score -1):

I can't quite tell exactly what you are trying to do with this function.  But I have highlighted a couple problems:

This will cause you problems.  As Size + Pos should always be bigger than StrLen.  Since Strlen should be equal to size.

```
if (Size < 1 || Size + Pos > StrLen) return true;
```

Rewrite it as:

```
if (Size < 1 ||  Pos > StrLen)
{
    return true;  
}
```

Also, this definition is not correct. This will assign the pointer to a location you do not want.

```
char * StrPos = Str + Pos + Size;
```

Correct this to :

```
char * StrPos = &Str[Pos];
```

Once you cut the string I don't know what you are trying to do.  I implemented and ran the program to simply append the cut string to end of the input and print it.  You can see this here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool CutString(char * Str, int Pos, int Size)
{
    int StrLen = strlen(Str);

    if (Size < 1 ||  Pos > StrLen)
    {
        return true;  
    }

    char * StrPos = &Str[Pos];

    printf("%s\n", StrPos);

    strcat(Str, StrPos);
    printf("%s", Str);

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    char input[26] = "WhatDoesThisDo?";
    CutString(input,5,14);

    return 0;
}
```